# python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zsm7incx/phonenumbers/ - Failed

Tags: linux, git, heroku, twilio, sendgrid

My 1st time using Heroku trying to create an application (Using SendGrid's Inbound Parse Webhook" and Twilio SMS to send and receive SMS messages via email).  Using Terminal in Linux via VirtualBox.

Procfile

web:gunicorn app:app

Requirements

(click link for screenshot of text file)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjUtG.jpg

I keep getting this error message:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing python-3.6.7
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip

   Collecting Flask==0.10.1 (from -r /tmp/build_a3cc99a3acb699a81c9d4cf2df05e742/requirements.txt (line 1))

     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/db/9c/149ba60c47d107f85fe52564133348458f093dd5e6b57a5b60ab9ac517bb/Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz (544kB)

   Collecting Jinja2==2.7.2 (from -r /tmp/build_a3cc99a3acb699a81c9d4cf2df05e742/requirements.txt (line 2))

     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/94/ca42176bf7a252ce1f5d165953013573dffdbe4b5dac07f57146146ea432/Jinja2-2.7.2.tar.gz (378kB)

   Collecting MarkupSafe==0.19 (from -r /tmp/build_a3cc99a3acb699a81c9d4cf2df05e742/requirements.txt (line 3))

     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/90/da092a12fb96e0c4cacc279d1f92819ae82bfa291e0a03afe8059518e91a/MarkupSafe-0.19.tar.gz

   Collecting Werkzeug==0.9.4 (from -r /tmp/build_a3cc99a3acb699a81c9d4cf2df05e742/requirements.txt (line 4))

     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/5e/8abc95630f9c4248edffed30592468f884e845ba656a959a12e452fafcec/Werkzeug-0.9.4.tar.gz (1.1MB)

   Collecting gunicorn==18.0 (from -r /tmp/build_a3cc99a3acb699a81c9d4cf2df05e742/requirements.txt (line 5))

     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/b3/23273452586e4923af43b2805292900ac784324e9d8ada8e0673ff7accd5/gunicorn-18.0-py33-none-any.whl (93kB)

   Collecting httplib2==0.8 (from -r /tmp/build_a3cc99a3acb699a81c9d4cf2df05e742/requirements.txt (line 6))

     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/cf/71451a11600b896b3e186361b73a971372cd2c124666798af8cd4ffa6ac8/httplib2-0.8.tar.gz (110kB)

   Collecting itsdangerous==0.23 (from -r /tmp/build_a3cc99a3acb699a81c9d4cf2df05e742/requirements.txt (line 7))

     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c1/6c/ceefb52b2a5d7d1f2b1b407a96892182161904478b9ef86049e7b8162cb6/itsdangerous-0.23.tar.gz (46kB)

   Collecting mock==1.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_a3cc99a3acb699a81c9d4cf2df05e742/requirements.txt (line 8))

     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/52/7edcd94f0afb721a2d559a5b9aae8af4f8f2c79bc63fdbe8a8a6c9b23bbe/mock-1.0.1.tar.gz (818kB)

   Collecting nose==1.3.1 (from -r /tmp/build_a3cc99a3acb699a81c9d4cf2df05e742/requirements.txt (line 9))

     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/a3/6df9d0d59cf0b20c505359ddef33d7ce4fe4388dba0948aadf3e75722f33/nose-1.3.1.tar.gz (274kB)

   Collecting phonenumbers==6.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_a3cc99a3acb699a81c9d4cf2df05e742/requirements.txt (line 10))

     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/66/ec/efb3d3200cd5ead52a7cbf750b9406740d493ae4a7f3ef8303a42b3a0c58/phonenumbers-6.0.0.tar.gz (1.7MB)

       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
         File "/tmp/pip-build-zsm7incx/phonenumbers/setup.py", line 33, in <module>
           from phonenumbers import __version__
         File "/tmp/pip-build-zsm7incx/phonenumbers/phonenumbers/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
           from .phonenumbermatcher import PhoneNumberMatch, PhoneNumberMatcher, Leniency
         File "/tmp/pip-build-zsm7incx/phonenumbers/phonenumbers/phonenumbermatcher.py", line 161, in <module>
           re.compile(u("(?u)(?:\\p{Z}-|-\\s)\\s*(.+)")),
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 233, in compile
           return _compile(pattern, flags)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 301, in _compile
           p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
           p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 855, in parse
           p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 416, in _parse_sub
           not nested and not items))

         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 765, in _parse
           p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 416, in _parse_sub
           not nested and not items))
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 502, in _parse
           code = _escape(source, this, state)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 401, in _escape
           raise source.error("bad escape %s" % escape, len(escape))
       sre_constants.error: bad escape \p at position 7
       ----------------------------------------

   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in     /tmp/pip-build-zsm7incx/phonenumbers/

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed
```

I have checked through multiple posts and tried quite a few things.  I upgraded setuptools.  How do I fix the above error?

Answer (score 1):

Seems it's an issue with old `phonenumbers` (you use version 6.0.0, current version is 8.10.2) and [Python 3.5](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/issues/75). You need either lower version of Python or higher version of `phonenumbers`.

Comment: Yep, so somehow I got this figured out and you were right  about using a lower version of python. I didn’t know that I had to “Add commit” the files after I edited the file that names the python version. Like I said, this is my first time using any of this stuff but I did get it figured out. Thank you so much!